Flyway custom migration in gradle
I have two docker container for two databases: One for production, one for testing.
I want the testing database container to be migrated with my flyway migrations of production to get the exact same database structure.
I tried
task flywayMigrateTesting(type: org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://db-testing:3306/prf2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    user = "prf2"
    password = "prf2"
    println "I was called"
}

And it was actually called, when I run ./gradlew clean build or ./gradlew flywayMigrateTesting. Then "I was called" is printed, but the database is still not migrated.
But when I replace the url of the productions database-container with the url of the testing database-container, it works as expected. So the container is set up correctly and connection is also no problem. The problem is to run a second flywayMigration in my build.gradle. It just don't want to do anything.
This is my docker-compose.yml
version: '2.4'

services:
  app:
    image: prf2-webapp-2_app-builder
    environment:
      flywayUrl: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/prf2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
      flywayUser: *****
      flywayPassword: *****
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
       image: mariadb:11.1
       restart: always
       environment:
         MARIADB_DATABASE: prf2
         MARIADB_USER: *****
         MARIADB_PASSWORD: *****
         MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
       volumes:
         - prf2DevDB:/var/lib/mysql
       ports:
         - "3308:3306"
  db-testing:
       image: mariadb:11.1
       restart: always
       environment:
         MARIADB_DATABASE: prf2
         MARIADB_USER: *****
         MARIADB_PASSWORD: *****
         MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
       volumes:
         - prf2TestDB:/var/lib/mysql
       ports:
         - "3308:3306"
volumes:
  prf2DevDB:
  prf2TestDB:
      

Googled sooo much. Even the solution (https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/gradle-task-184127407.html) of the official flyway documentation does not work.
